# Replace two nested loops with a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Is there a way to replace the following code with a dictionary comprehension?

```
d = {}

for i in xrange(A):
    for j in xrange(B):

         d[(i, j)] = f(i, j)
```

I'm using Python2.7 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d = {(i,j):f(i,j) for i in xrange(A) for j in xrange(B)}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's usually a good idea to replace nested loops with [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
d = { p: f(*p) for p in product(range(A), range(B))}
```